# iOS Credit card recurring payment with paypal

Tags: ios, paypal, authorize.net

Paypal has released new SDK for iOS developer : [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)

This SDK allow two kind of payment:

1. Single payments
2. Future payments

I need to implement Future payments in my app so user only have to enter his payment detail one time.
And every other time Amount is transfer automatically.

**Problem** : Single payments can be done with PapPal account and Credit Card but Future payments is only work with PayPal Account ([Make future payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/)).

As other option I try [Authorize.net](http://Authorize.net) But it don't allow Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) with iOS SDK[Choose an API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/).

One other option I think is doing credit card payment with [Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/). I scan credit card with [card.io](https://www.card.io/) And use REST API to make transfer. I save this detail for future use and every time user require payment I use this saved detail with REST API. But I am not very sure with this option.

So how can I develop such functionality in my app so that user don't have to enter his Credit card detail? Is it
any way possible with PayPal or Authorize.net? or I have to go for other payment gateway like [stripe](https://stripe.com/).

Comment: I need to do the same , can you share how you did it please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CRDave, Dave from PayPal here.

You're correct that the PayPal iOS SDK does not currently include the option of authorizing a credit card for Future Payments.

You're also correct that directly using the REST API will allow you to save the user's credit card information in the PayPal Vault, so that you can subsequently bill the same card in the future. It sounds like this would work fine for your case.

Comment: Is there any special reason why payPal iOS SDK don't include Credit Card in future payment?

Comment: @CRDave there have been some internal reasons. But later this year we will be adding that support in one form or another.

Comment: @dave-goldman do you know whether the preferred method for this is to call the rest api to vault the card directly from the mobile device or should the mobile device send the card info to the server and have it do the vaulting?

Comment: @broughten either approach should work. However, sending the card info to your server is less secure for the customer. If the mobile device directly calls the REST API to vault the card, then your server never needs to know that card info - better for customer, and better for you in case of an audit or a breech.

Comment: @CRDave 

n one of my iOS application. I need to implement payment function. In which we need to add card via paypal SDK. I have reviewed Paypal framework. But didn't get any positive methods in it which fulfills my need. In my case we don't want to send credit card information at our server.
So If anyone having knowledge about it. Then please share it with me.