# One time login in Pay-pal

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

Can i save login credentials or other key value in pay-pal.i want only one time pay-pal login in my application.

Comment: Elaborate more in your question, no idea what do you want to achieve. If you do want to share tokens between apps (= your apps), you can use shared keychain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications

Comment: You want that once user login in your app than when ever he need to pay he don't have to give paypal detail. Am I right?

Comment: yes @CRDave you are right. yes i want one time login into playpal account , and when ever he need to pay he don't to give paypal detail.

Comment: @CRDave  is there any way to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve this than you have two way:

1. Use REST Paypal API : Save username and password of user in secure place and use appropriate API to make payment.
2. Use Paypal-iOS-SDK (You should use this) : If you are going to use this option than you have good news that Paypal iOS SDK 2 is launched (which is used by UBER) which provide this feature under future payments option.

Read following document to understand this :

- [Introduction and overview of future payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/make-future-payment/)

***Implementation*** : To implement this you need to code on both side (Mobile and Server). Following link will guide you through this process.

- [Future Payments Mobile Integration](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_mobile.md)
- [Future Payments Server-Side Integration](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md)

I suggest you to read all document in this two place:

1. [PayPal Mobile SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/)
2. [PayPal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)

For some extra reading of Paypal mobile : [Paypal Forward Mobile](https://www.paypal-forward.com/mobile/)

I hope this will help in your work.

***Note*** : If you want to implement this same thing with credit card (not Paypal account but use paypal to precess credit card) than visit : [iOS Credit card recurring payment with paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034287/ios-credit-card-recurring-payment-with-paypal)

Comment: Thanks @CRDave i think it will helpful for me.